# Android studio "Could not find installation home path. Please make sure bin/idea.properties is present in the installation directory"

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

I installed a new version of Android Studio on Windows (see version below)
Now when I run `npx cap open android` in my Ionic Capacitor I get the error below.

[image]

I have tried changing the PATH environment variables with no success.
Android Studio is now installed in

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
```

previously it was

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
```

Any help appreciated.

Android studio version:

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8139111, built on February 2, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

delete
`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`
and rename
`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1`
to
`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`
should  solve the problem.